# Defining + operation on case class

Tags: scala

I want to define a + operation for a case class in Scala. I have:

```
final case class Buffer(
  field1: Seq[Long],
  field2: Long
){
  def +(that: Buffer): Buffer = Buffer(
    (this.field1, that.field1).zipped.map(_ + _),
    this.field2 + that.field2
  )
}
```

the only problem is that I would like my code to support something like (buffer is not "empty"):

```
Buffer.empty + buffer = buffer + Buffer.empty = buffer
```

i.e defining a 0, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Define an `empty` val in the companion object of **Buffer** - Anyways, what you want is a [**Monoid**](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/monoid.html) but **cats** and **Spark** are on somewhat opposite sides of how to approach **Scala**, you may want to take a look to [**frameless**](https://github.com/typelevel/frameless) but that may be too many things to learn for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create method empty in the companion object of your class.
It could look like that:

```
object Buffer {
    
  def empty: Buffer = new Buffer(Seq(), 0)
    
}
```

But it has one problem. You want `+` operator to be have correct identity element (and be commutative). But in your current implementation of `+` it works like this:

```
Buffer(Seq(1,2,3)) + Buffer.empty //Buffer(Seq(), 0)
```

The problem is related to how `zip` function works. If you zip shorter `Seq` with a longer one, the result will have a size of shorter (longer will be truncated).
There are many ways you could tackle that issue, but I think the easiest way would be to use `zipAll`, where you could specify "default" value which will be used when one of the sequences is shorter:

```
def +(that: Buffer): Buffer =
   Buffer(
     field1.zipAll(that.field1, 0L, 0L).map(a => a._1 + a._2),
     field2 + that.field2
   )
```

You could also share single instance of empty buffer and make `empty` `val` instead of `def`. In this case it's important, that you use immutable Seq.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Seq

object Buffer {
    
  val empty: Buffer = new Buffer(Seq(), 0)
    
}
```

Comment: It would be better to use a `val` for empty, wouldn't it?